# Why # comes in URL

Tags: javascript, html, css

I downloaded a HTML based template to create a static website. I replaced all content that i need to add in my website.

When i run index.html file in my local system, it works properly. After uploading to server -  [puneetchawla.com](http://puneetchawla.com)

when first time website open, it works proper. But when i click on menu bar, it opens page with adding '#' after domain name before page name.

Ex.

```
http://puneetchawla.com/#resume.html
```

This '#' does not display or comes in my local system. It only shows when i upload website to server. I don't know why '#' comes. It should not come.

I am not able to understand which code i need to share with you. I can share code which you want. Explain me the reason why '#' comes and how can i get rid of it.

Comment: This is using HTML5 History API. Do you want to not use that, or continue to use this API but not have the `#` ? (Do you want full pages reload, or AJAX page reload?)

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for reply. No, I don't want to use that.. i don't need any API. I just want to remove #.

Comment: Check my comment, I will tell you how to remove this functionality in a moment

Comment: @downvoter - can you please explain why this question deserve downvotes. My question clearly indicates about issue that i am getting. martin give answers and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is defined in line `190` of `Template.js`, when viewing the prettified version in Chrome.

```
_initAjaxPagesLoading: function(a, b) {
    a && !this.menu.isFileProtocol() && (b || (b = "a"),
    $(b, a).click(function(a) {
        a.which > 1 || a.ctrlKey || (a.preventDefault(),
        document.location.hash = "#" + $(this).attr("href"))
    }
    ))
},
```

Remove that function, and also its references on lines 88 and 98:

```
initBlog: function() {
    // Remove this:
    this._initAjaxPagesLoading($("section.blog"))
},
initPortfolio: function() {
    $(".page-portfolio__item").each(function() {
        $(this).hoverdir({
            hoverDelay: 50
        })
    }
    ),
    // Remove this:
    this._initAjaxPagesLoading($("section.page-portfolio"))
},
```

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for reply. I just downloaded a template and I just want to open my page normally without changing more in coding. I think, if i turn off javascript, it's not a good way (not sure). I think, just remove the # fragment of this code without changing any other is a best way to solve it.

Comment: @PuneetChawla I didn't suggest that as a solution, that was a way to test where the problem was coming from. Someone had proposed it could be server - this rules that out. If you read my current solution you'll see that I am only suggesting to remove the part of the script that causes this behaviour

Comment: @PuneetChawla Did the template.js you downloaded come already minified?

Comment: Yes i didn't do anything in template.js file.

Comment: Thanks. It removed that #.. I am proud of your skills.

Answer (score 0):

Your Template.js has this code in it (I found it at Line 1, Column 3675):

```
$(b,a).click(function(a){a.which>1||a.ctrlKey||(a.preventDefault(),document.location.hash="#"+$(this).attr("href"))})
```

This is taking the links' `href`s and prepending `#` to them when you click them.

Comment: Hi divinecomedian, Thanks for reply. Tell me now what i need to remove or replace. I don't knowledge about this coding or how to solve it.

Comment: My answer has your solution

Comment: Check out @Martin 's answer.  He seems to have an actual solution.